# General formula for 1, 2, 9, 48, 300, 2160, ....

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the general formula for this sequence $$1, 2, 9, 48, 300, 2160, ...?$$

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C9%2C48%2C300%2C2160).

Comment: Anything we want it to be, so long as it fits the given information.

Comment: i searched in google with ''1, 2, 9, 48, 300, 2160 oeis'' but google was not showing. Thanks.

Comment: Well, how would you describe what the sequence is doing? What is the next value?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [sequence A074143](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C9%2C48%2C300%2C2160) in OEIS.

Despite the common association of math with "pattern recognition", one cannot identify a sequence just based on the first few terms.  You will need to specify a recursion or another unambiguous description of your sequence for us to know for sure what sequence it is.

Answer (score 1):

Since

A(n) = [A(n-1) / (n-1)] * n^2,

We have

A(n) = n! * n/2

Answer (score 0):

The on line encyclopedia of integer sequences says:
$a_1=1$ and $a_n=n(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i)$